# Tkinter destroy message before execution of a command

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to  build one tkinter based application, where I am reading directory location and file extensions from another file. Here I want to display two messages one after another, first it would be "files are uploading" second it would be "files are uploaded".
I am using below code for this whole job, but messages are displayed incorrectly, specially the first message does not displays, if it displays by changing code, then it never get destroyed, and second messages appears on next line of first message
code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd,datetime,os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import shutil
import time
# Create an instance of tkinter frame
root = Tk()
# Set the geometry of tkinter frame
root.geometry("700x350")
def open_file():
    df=pd.read_excel('config.xlsx')
    ext=eval(df.iloc[0]['location'])
    path=df.iloc[1]['location']
    #root.withdraw()
# file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    filez = filedialog.askdirectory()
    lb=Label(root, text = "Files are uploading:")
    lb.pack()

    mydir = os.path.join(path, datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    #filez = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root,filetypes=[('.netfiles Files', ext)])
    #print(listdir(filez))
    l=listdir(filez)
    time.sleep(50)
    lb.destroy()
    lb=Label(root, text = "Files are uploded:", fg="black")
    lb.pack()
    onlyfiles=[]
    os.makedirs(mydir)
#    onlyfiles = [filez+'/'+f  if (isfile(join(filez, f)) and f.endswith(ext)) else shutil.copy2(filez+'\\'+f, mydir+'\\'+f) for f in l]
    for  f in l:
         if (isfile(join(filez, f)) and f.endswith(ext)):
            onlyfiles.append(f)
            fl=open(filez+'\\'+f,'r')
            content = fl.read()
            fl.close()
         else:
            shutil.copy2(filez+'\\'+f,mydir+'\\'+f)
# Add a Label widget
label = Label(root, text="Upload .net files", font=('Georgia 13'))
label.pack(pady=10)

# Create a Button
try:
 
    ttk.Button(root, text="Browse", command=open_file).pack(pady=20)

except error as e:
    print(e)
root.mainloop()
```

After clicking on browse button message :- "Files are uploading" should be prompted.
As soon as files are uploaded , first message should be destroyed and in place of first message
second message:- "Files are uploaded" should be prompted

Comment: Add `lb.update()` after first `lb.pack()`.